# How to run archive-node in substrate chains

Tags: archive

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-sync#running-an-archive-node.

this is my start command:

```shell
./target/release/node --chain specs/testnet/testnet.json --name "test-archive-node" --pruning archive --base-path /tmp/archive-node --unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors all  --bootnodes /ip4/xxxxxxx/tcp/40335/p2p/xxxxxxx
```

this log:

```shell
2022-08-30 09:56:51 Test Node
2022-08-30 09:56:51 ✌️  version 0.0.1-91477983703
2022-08-30 09:56:51 ❤️  by Test Developers, 2021-2022
2022-08-30 09:56:51  Chain specification: Testnet
2022-08-30 09:56:51   Node name: test-archive-node
2022-08-30 09:56:51  Role: FULL
2022-08-30 09:56:51  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/archive-node/chains/testnet/db/full
2022-08-30 09:56:51 ⛓  Native runtime: test-node (node-1.tx1.au1)
2022-08-30 09:56:54 Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs
2022-08-30 09:56:54   Local node identity is: *************
2022-08-30 09:56:54  Operating system: linux
2022-08-30 09:56:54  CPU architecture: x86_64
2022-08-30 09:56:54  Target environment: gnu
2022-08-30 09:56:54  CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8369B CPU @ 2.70GHz
2022-08-30 09:56:54  CPU cores: 1
2022-08-30 09:56:54  Memory: 7814MB
2022-08-30 09:56:54  Kernel: 5.4.0-123-generic
2022-08-30 09:56:54  Linux distribution: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
2022-08-30 09:56:54  Virtual machine: yes
2022-08-30 09:56:54  Highest known block at #0
2022-08-30 09:56:54 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615
2022-08-30 09:56:54 Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=127.0.0.1:9933, allowed origins=None
2022-08-30 09:56:54 Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=0.0.0.0:9944, allowed origins=None
2022-08-30 09:56:54 creating instance on iface 172.24.192.69
2022-08-30 09:56:55 creating instance on iface 172.17.0.1
2022-08-30 09:56:55 creating instance on iface 172.18.0.1
2022-08-30 09:56:59  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xecba…5342), finalized #0 (0xecba…5342), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2022-08-30 09:57:04  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xecba…5342), finalized #0 (0xecba…5342), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
^[[A^[[D2022-08-30 09:57:09  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xecba…5342), finalized #0 (0xecba…5342), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2022-08-30 09:57:14  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xecba…5342), finalized #0 (0xecba…5342), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2022-08-30 09:57:19  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xecba…5342), finalized #0 (0xecba…5342), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2022-08-30 09:57:24  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xecba…5342), finalized #0 (0xecba…5342), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
```

Comment: The node is running. What is your question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot with `--pruning archive` or `--validator`. It will set the node to archive mode.

---

If you run with `--pruning 1000` again on the achieve DB. It will throw an error. I think that's a way to verify this. (Does anyone have a better way to verify this?)

Comment: is it still applied? as far as I understand validators are **full** nodes by default?